# Python Nested For Loop Array Comparison - Possibility of Optimization?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to optimize a nested for loops that **compares an element in the array with the rest of the elements in the array**.

There's two part, the first part is for example,  an Array has 3 elements, and each element is a dictionary:

`[{"someKey_1":"a"}, {"someKey_1":"b"}, {"somekey_1":"a"}]`

---

1st iteration(1st element compares with 2nd element):

Test key of "someKey" for two elements, since a != b, then we do nothing

---

2st iteration(1st element compares with 3nd element):

Test key of "someKey" for two elements, since a == a, we do some logic

---

The code:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    for idx_2, val_2 in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
        if (val['someKey'] == val_2['someKey'] and idx != idx_2):
                #Some Logic
```

---

The second part is very similar to the previous example (3 items in the list), in the same dictionary, we have an array associated with a key (now there's a single dictionary with two keys in each element of the array), let's say:

```
[{"someKey_1":[b,f]}{"someKey_2":a}, 
{"someKey_1":[e,f]}{"someKey_2":b}, 
{"somekey_1":[h,k]}{"someKey_2":c}]
```

---

1st iteration (1st element compares with 2nd element):

loops through the array with the key: someKey_1

`b==b` (2nd element's someKey_2), then do some logic

`f!=b` (2nd element's someKey_2), no logic is done

---

2nd iteration (1st element compares with 3rd element):

loops through the array with the key: someKey_1

`b==c` (3rd element's someKey_2), then do some logic

`f!=c` (3rd element's someKey_2), no logic is done

---

The code:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    for idx_2, val_2 in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
        for pred in val['someKey_1']:
            if(val_2['someKey_2'] == pred):
                #Some Logic
```

---

Currently the runtime for the first nested loop: 21 seconds, and the second nested loop is around 19 seconds. Compared to other processes, ranging from 1-2 seconds, this part is clearly a bottleneck.

Can anybody point me to the right direction on how to optimize this piece of simple, yet extremely time consuming code?

Comment: if you're comparing 1 versus 2, do you really need to compare 2 versus 1?

Comment: No for the first nested loop, but it is required for second nested loop. I was thinking is there were any way to make this O(n)

Comment: Could you combine the nested loops? Instead of comprising a skiplist and then reiterating to parse, could you not simply skip the items in one loop using if statements, and possibly continue?

Comment: dictionaries don't have indices (0..n) (you can't reliable use enumerate as the order might differ). Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve with the code?

Comment: Set_of_pk_values is an array that contains dictionaries. There's keys in the dictionary whose content I'm trying to compare.

Comment: @MeetTitan could you try to provide an example? Thanks

Comment: SkipList is important, because in the end, we will construct a new array that does not have indices in set_of_pk_values recorded in skipList.

Comment: You can do that without looping twice, though.

Comment: @MeetTitan Is it possible to provide some examples? Thanks

Comment: Put the keyword `continue` at the end of your first loop, and put another condition in and you'll skip the items you would have put into your skipList without having to reiterate.

Comment: In your second data set, is `{"someKey_1":[b,f]}{"someKey_2":a}` supposed to be a single dictionary with two keys and two values, or two separate `dict`s (with a missing a comma between them)?

Comment: They are the single dictionaries with two keys.

Comment: Cilyan has tested the various solutions here and found mine was fastest, while the one you have marked as accepted was slower and produced an incorrect answer while mine did not. Just saying. gist.github.com/Cilyan/50b9ee3e2dad67bb8a6b

Comment: This sounds much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you want to optimize the constant factors of an O(n²) nested loops - there is no way to do this algorithm behaving better asymptotically with this little information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Optimization of part 1

## Original

Man, this is bad:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    for idx_2, val_2 in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
        if (val['someKey'] == val_2['someKey'] and idx != idx_2):
            do_stuff()
```

## Step 1

Just skip the indices of the elements you've already tried (`==` is commutative):

```
for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values[:-1]):
    for val_2 in set_of_pk_values[idx+1:]
        if (val['someKey'] == val_2['someKey']):
            do_stuff()
```

## Step 0.1

Rename that. It's ugly.

```
for idx, first_dic in enumerate(set_of_pk_values[:-1]):
    for second_dic in set_of_pk_values[idx+1:]
        if (first_dic['someKey'] == second_dic['someKey']):
            do_stuff()
```

## Step 2

Now, the `if` in every loop iteration is bothersome. Replace it by filtering the reduced list:

```
hits = []
for idx, first_dic in enumerate(set_of_pk_values[:-1]):
    hits += (first_dic['someKey'], filter(lambda dic: dic['someKey'] == first_dic['someKey'], set_of_pk_values[idx:1]) )
```

`hits` now contains a list of match tuples: `hits[i] = (` mathing first element `,` list of matches that have idx > first element`)`.

## Step 3

Dictionary lookups are expensive. Replace them using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
getter = itemgetter("someKey")
hits = []
for idx, first_dic in enumerate(set_of_pk_values[:-1]):
    hits += (getter(first_dic), filter(lambda dic: getter(dic) == getter(first_dic), set_of_pk_values[idx:1]) )
```

## Step 4

Sit back and look. The iterations of the for loop don't really rely on the state of last iteration. Time for list comprehensions.

```
from operator import itemgetter
getter = itemgetter("someKey")
hits = [ ( getter(first_dic), filter(lambda dic: getter(dic) == getter(first_dic), set_of_pk_values[idx:-1]) ) for idx, first_dic in enumerate(set_of_pk_values[:-1])]
```

Comment: For step 3, where does second_dic come from?

Comment: @user1157751: typo, fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is it possible for hits to give me the indexes that matches in set_of_pk_values? Also for step 4, it seems that an open bracket isn't matching with an ending bracket? ==> (getter(first_dic).

Comment: @user1157751: thanks for spotting that typo. Also, yes of course; just exchange the first element of the tuple, i.e. replace `( getter(first_dic) ,... `
by `( idx, ...`.

Comment: Thanks again. This might be impossible, but is it possible to get the index of set_of_pk_values[idx:1] used to compare with first_dic in step 3?

Comment: If you want to do that, your problem is probably different from what you demand in your question

Comment: The logic inside requires to combine the keys from second_dic to dic. Only keys like 'someKey' exists on all dictionary, but let's say 'someKey_2' might not exist on dic, but since 'someKey' is the same for second_dic and dic, I will copy 'someKey_2' to dic.

Comment: Well, thanks for your effort! I've been working on this for weeks, and I haven't got a solution :c.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Apart from a (valuable) readability improvement, I doubt replacing the lambda by itemgetter brings any time optimization. [Implementation of itemgetter](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1aad901e0307/Lib/operator.py#l253). If I'm wrong, could you please explain, I'd be interested.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Also a question on Step 4, *The iterations of the for loop don't really rely on the state of last iteration.*: It took me some time to understand what you meant. For me the "state of last iteration" concerns all the variables involved in the loop body. This would be wrong, as the scope of these variables survives the loop, and the iteration is based on iterators. But I guess now you are talking about the fact that the virtual machine has to read the opcodes over and over again, in contrary to a list comprehension?

Comment: @Cilyan: exactly; the opcodes of each iteration is *exactly the same*. You can even re-use the same PyObjects you temporarily created in the first iteration.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Trying to run your code: `set_of_pk_values[idx:1]` there is a typo, should be `set_of_pk_values[idx:-1]`. I also do not get it about the PyObjects... They are anyway mostly just pointers pushed around so probably not "created" in the for loop.

Comment: you're right about the typo. CPython needs to understand the loop; everything passed to a function as a parameter has to be a PyObject, so CPython will have to create some.

Comment: Ok, understood. At least the arg tuple. I'm still trying to run your code but without success. That would be great if you came shortly on the chat.

Answer (score 5):

First off, I believe this should be posted on CodeReview, not StackOverflow.

StackOverflow is for getting help with code that doesn't work.
CodeReview is for getting help with code that does work, but you want to make it better.

Second, here's some suggestions on optimizing it:

- Don't `enumerate()` inside the loop.
- Use slices in the first scenario to avoid pointless comparisons.

Here's how I would rewrite your first scenario:

```
# Check if two dictionary with the key 'predecessor' are the same,
# and they are NOT the same index (otherwise it would be comparing themselves)
# set_of_pk_values is an array of dictionaries.
for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    for val_2 in set_of_pk_values[idx+1:]:  # Note the slice and lack of enumerate
        if (val['predecessor'] == val_2['predecessor']):  # Don't waste time checking indexes
            # Do Something Here, also we don't want to compare itself, because it will be true
```

Instead of `for\if`, use `if in`:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    if val in set_of_pk_values[idx+1:]:
        # Do Something Here, also we don't want to compare itself, because it will be true.
```

<del>If you really want to enumerate, since you just want the same enumeration multiple times, I would just do it once outside the loop and store it in a variable, then loop over it. Here's what I mean:</del>

I was incorrect, the below doesn't work, see the comments.

```
# Doesn't work, see comments.
# from itertools import islice
# whatIEnumerate = enumerate(set_of_pk_values)
# for idx, val in whatIEnumerate:
    # for idx_2, val_2 in islice(whatIEnumerate, idx+1, None):
        # ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! Next time if I have code optimizations I will post to CodeReview. The problem is, each val inside set_of_pk_values are unique if the consider all of the keys. But there will be repeating values of the same key across all dictionaries. The first part is to compare if there are any keys are the same. This line: if val in set_of_pk_values[idx+1:]: seems to compare the dictionaries, and not the item inside the key['predecessors'].

Comment: @user1157751: I offered multiple optimizations because I wasn't sure what was important details and what wasn't. If the `if in` doesn't work, use one of the other two optimizations.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: There is one thing preventing me from upvoting this post, it's the way you use the `whatIEnumerate`. This won't work like this because it's an iterator (in python3, or an enumerate object in python2) and as such is not subscriptable. Your idea not to enumerate inside the first for loop is however valid.

Comment: @Cilyan: Fixed by replacing the slice notation with `islice()`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare still not: https://bpaste.net/show/1dd12178faea . As an iterator, it is **consumed**.

Comment: @Cilyan: I've struck out the incorrect portion of my answer since that part doesn't work (but I left it in so people can easily see what the comments are talking about without having to go through the edit history.)

Answer (score 3):

Iterations in Python are slower than iterations in C. It's better to do the iterations in C by using the Python libraries. Funny that nobody mentioned [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) here...

`itertools.combinations` makes unique combinations in C and then returns a generator for the combinations:

```
import itertools
import operator
getter = operator.itemgetter('someKey_1')

for a, b in itertools.combinations(set_of_pk_values, 2):
    if getter(a) == getter(b):
        # logic?
```

Comment: Have you tried `timeit` on your answer and the other answers? Just curious how much better it performs.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Here an attempt to time the solutions. I must say, I'm very surprised with the results... Any comment/critics welcome on my code. https://gist.github.com/Cilyan/50b9ee3e2dad67bb8a6b

Comment: @Cilyan: Wait, so my solution is the fastest of them all, then?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Err... unless the one from Marcus Müller starts working and proves to be faster, yes! I'm rather suprised that a double for works better as combinations which is internally accelerated, but that's what the results show... :)